# Not equal to conditions in while loop

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am building a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I am trying to figure out why my while statement will not recognize the correct input on the first try. Thank you for any help in advance.

`
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.util.Random;

```
public class RPC
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
 //Utilities
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
Random r = new Random ();

//variables

int userwins =0;
int computerwins =0;
int numberofgames = 0;
int randomnumber = 0;
String userpick = "";
String computerpick = "";


// Welcome statement
System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!");


//Get the number of games from the user
System.out.println("Please enter the number of rounds you would like to play:");
numberofgames = in.nextInt();

//Flush the buffer
in.nextLine();


// Game play for the number of times the user specified.

for (int i=1; i <= numberofgames; i++)
  {


  System.out.println("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?:");
  userpick = in.nextLine();

  while (!userpick.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && !userpick.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && !userpick.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"));
  {
     System.out.println("Sorry," +userpick+ " is not a valid entry.Please enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors.");
     userpick = in.nextLine();

  }

  //Make a random choice
  randomnumber = r.nextInt(3)+1; 

  if (randomnumber == 1)
  {
  computerpick = ("rock");
  }
  if (randomnumber == 2)
  {
  computerpick = ("paper");
  }
  if (randomnumber == 3)
  {
  computerpick = ("scissors");
  }

  //Decide who wins the round

  if (userpick.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
     if (computerpick.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
        System.out.println("Rock beats scissors. You win!");
else if (computerpick.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
        System.out.println("Paper beats rock. The computer wins!");
    else
        System.out.println("Computer chooses rock. It's a tie.");
} 
else if (userpick.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
     if (computerpick.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
        System.out.println("Scissors beats paper. The computer wins!");
else if (computerpick.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
        System.out.println("Paper beats rock. You win!");
    else
        System.out.println("Computer chooses paper. It's a tie.");
} 
else if (userpick.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
     if (computerpick.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
        System.out.println("Rock beats scissors. The computer wins!");
else if (computerpick.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
        System.out.println("Scissors beats paper. You win!");
    else
        System.out.println("Computer chooses scissors. It's a tie.");

  }
 }
```

}
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon which is terminating the `while` statement

```
while (...);
           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after the for loop. Semicolon after while/for/if means its a null statement which means the very next block of codes with in braces acts just as a block which will always gets evaluated irrespective of whether the condition holds true or not.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon generally ends a line in java. In order to make the while loop to run you need to remove the semi column.

Comment: The semicolon ends a statement, not a line. You *could* write as many statements in one line as you wish.

Comment: we agree to disagree